# How to stop a private sub from running with a password

Tags: vba, button, passwords, private

I have two private subs for active x check boxes. When I click one button another button is locked. I want to create a button that would act as an override, where if I type a password then the two private subs won't run.

```
Private Sub CRM_box_Click()
If CRM_box.Value = True Then
    CheckBox14.Value = False
    CheckBox14.Enabled = False
Else
    CheckBox14.Value = False
    CheckBox14.Enabled = True
End If

Private Sub RMP_box_Click()
If RMP_box.Value = True Then
    CRM_box.Value = False
    CRM_box.Enabled = False
Else
    CRM_box.Value = False
    CRM_box.Enabled = True
End If
```

Comment: What do you mean *"**won't run**"?*  ...so that another section of code won't call them, or are you trying to prevent users from going into the VBA and running them manually?  If this is a security issue then I should warn you, there's no such thing as a 100% secure shared Office document; only ways to make it harder for people to do what they want.

Answer (score 0):

To 'override' the `Private Sub` for your check boxes, you could do the following:

In your VBE, create a Module (if you don't already have one) and enter `Public override As Boolean` on the first line.

For each of your Private Subs for the Check Boxes, add the following above your current `If` statement: `If override = False Then Exit Sub` like so:

```
Private Sub CRM_box_Click()

    If override = False Then Exit Sub

    If CRM_box.Value = True Then
        RMP_box.Value = False
        RMP_box.Enabled = False
    Else
        RMP_box.Value = False
        RMP_box.Enabled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

For the password part of your question you could create a `UserForm`.

If you're not firmiliar with UserForms, there are a lot of tutorials and instructions on how to create them by searching something like "How to create a userform in excel" in Google or equivalent.

I made a simple `UserForm` with a `label`, `textbox` and `commandbutton`. [See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pkFR.png)

For the `commandbutton`, you could use the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim pwrd As String
    Dim setPwrd As String

    pwrd = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
    setPwrd = "abc" 'Change this string to whatever you want your password to be

        If pwrd = setPwrd Then
            override = False
            Unload UserForm1
        Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect Password" & vbNewLine & "Please try again.", vbCritical
        End If
    End Sub
```

When you enter your password into the textbox and click the commandbutton, the vba compares your input with the variable `setPassword`. If it's a match it set's the Public variable `override` to `False`. If the password doesn't match you get a message to try again.

If `override = False` it directs your `Private Sub` for your check boxes to `Exit Sub` before executing the code - Your code is 'overridden'.

In summary:

1. Declare a Public Variable as a Boolean.
2. Set an If statement in each Private Sub for your check boxes.
3. Create a UserForm to enter a Password.
4. Write the code to set a password and for what happens when you submit your password.

You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50166285/9663006) helpful in understanding ways you can prevent other users from getting around your password form.

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly as you described.

One question, once I set the password and exit sub kicks in is there a way to reverse the command?

I tried to create a second command button with a different password to flip override = true, but then my original code doesn't run.

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! 

In your code for the check boxes, add `Else` to the end of `If override = False Then Exit Sub`. 

For your second command button, copy the exact code for the first command button and change `override = False` to `override = True`. If you want a different password for the second button that shouldn't be an issue at all. Just remember which password is for which button.

If it's answered your question, be sure to mark the answer as accepted to help other community members if they have the same question.